# PHP : Very big no sense with variable

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony 2 app.
I've an object manage with Doctrine which it has `private $beginDate` which is a \DateTime.

I've a function very important :

```
public function isBefore($timestamp)
{
    print_r($this->beginDate);
    echo "<br />";
    $date = $this->beginDate->format("Y-m-d"); // (line 44)
    echo $date;
    echo "<br />";
    return $this->beginDate->getTimestamp() < $timestamp;
}
```

The first print_r display : **DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-01-01 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris )**

The `beginDate->format` give me : **Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /var/.../GS/AcmeBundle/Entity/ARecur.php line 44**

`echo $date` display : **2015-01-01**

And `$this->beginDate->getTimestamp()` said nothing because the line 44 is blocking others errors (but without the line 44, i've the same error on this line !)

My PHP version :

> PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u14 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2014 08:36:44) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Any ideas (Sorry for my bad english)
Have a good day :)

Comment: `echo $date;` would not display anything if the error is thrown on `$date = $this->beginDate->format("Y-m-d");`  Are you positive that the error is on line 44 of the same file you are debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, not nice but it doesn't crash my app :

```
public function isBefore($timestamp)
{
    $myDate = json_decode(json_encode($this->beginDate), true); 
    return strtotime($myDate['date']) < $timestamp;
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all.  Are you posting actual code or are you "cleaning it up"?  Like @STLMikey, I suspect you are looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `echo "<br />"` and try, it is not good the mix you html in you code.

Comment: It's for the debug, my really function is :

    public function isBefore($timestamp)
    {
     return $this->beginDate->getTimestamp() < $timestamp;
    }


And it not solve the problem.

Comment: print out $this, see if any difference

Comment: In this, i can the object like **DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-01-01 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Paris )**

Comment: so that's the object in the first print? what about the second print? in the second print, just print out $this

Comment: append ->format("Y-m-d")  to your first object, if errors, then you know what it is